# RSpec - How to test extended classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a model that I've extended, whats the best way testing both the original and extended class?
Currently, I'm just testing the Dataset model. Is there a way of including Datasets tests within Section? Or do I just write tests for anything added to Section?

Thanks in advance.

**Models**

```
class Dataset < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  # ...
end

class Section < Dataset
  # ...
end
```

**Spec**

```
describe Dataset do
  it "should have a valid name" do
    should validate_presence_of(:name)
  end
  # ...
end
```

Comment: I'd spec parent and spec the child is really a child

Comment: The section spec should only cover your section class. You wouldn't test ActiveRecord in your dataset spec, would you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best thing is to have one set of tests for the parent class, and a separate set of tests for any additional behavior that the child class adds. Testing the shared behavior in separate tests for each class would be redundant and difficult to maintain. And including parent tests in the child's tests shouldn't be necessary - once it's tested, it's tested.

Comment: isn't there the danger that the child class breaks some of the parent class behaviour in an unexpected fashion?  seems like it would be nice to have a quick way of re-running all the parent class tests on the child class ...

Answer (score 3):

You can use a shared example group:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group

Answer (score 1):

At first this is not extended class but inherited class.

If there is anything special in sub class, new method or overwriting, just test it separately. If nothing new, test parent class is enough.